# Padding/spacing with \cellcolor

Tags: tables, spacing, color

I have a working table with cell colors:

```
\newcommand{\ye}{\cellcolor{yellow}}
\newcommand{\re}{\cellcolor{red}}
\begin{tabular}{l l l}
        & A        & B\\
Test1   & \gr Good & \re Bad \\
test2   & \ye OK   & \re Bad \\
test3   & \gr Good & \re Good \\
\end{tabular}
```

However it would improve the readability a lot, if I there were some spacing between the colors, just like the examples on page two of [The official guide](http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/colortbl/colortbl.pdf).

Based on section 4.3 and 4.1 in [this guide](http://www.tug.org/pracjourn/2007-1/mori/mori.pdf) I have tried both:

```
\newcommand{\gr}{\cellcolor{green}[0.5\tabcolsep][0.5\tabcolsep]}
\newcommand{\gr}{\cellcolor{green}[0.5\tabcolsep]}
```

Both of those throws these two errors (multiple times) when I compile.

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
```

If i try any of

```
\newcommand{\gr}{\cellcolor{green}[0.5][0.5]}
\newcommand{\gr}{\cellcolor{green}[0.5]}
```

The text [0.5][0.5] is just inserted as normal text.

So **my question** is: How to add padding/spacing to the \cellcolor command, so I achieve a small white border between the cells? Preferably I would be able to control vertical and horizontal padding sperately

Answer (score 5):

`\tabcolsep` is a *length* so you can set

```
\setlength\tabcolsep{5pt}
```

*before* the table to set the spacing between columns, then use a *smaller* amount (such as `0pt` in the color optional arguments so perhaps

```
\cellcolor{green}[1pt]
```

note it has to have a unit such as `pt` not a number as in the examples in your question.

Comment: Tried it out. The '\tabcolsep' seems to work fine, but '\cellcolor{green}[1pt]' still only puts [1pt] as text into the cell. 
Is there a command length for rows, '\tabrowsep' doesn't works

Comment: Does anyone know how to get this to work? I tried to read the code, but it‘s beyond my current level of TeX trickery.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a half solution. It only solves vertical spacing, and is a bit hacky.

The solution is to use `\midrule` defined in `booktabs` to create the spacing. A normal `\hrule` or `\hline` does not work. To avoid the black ruler simply make it white using `\arrayrulecolor{white}` so the entire table will look like:

```
\newcommand{\gr}{\cellcolor{green}}
\newcommand{\ye}{\cellcolor{yellow}}
\newcommand{\re}{\cellcolor{red}}
\arrayrulecolor{white}
\begin{tabular}{l l l}           \toprule
        & A        & B        \\ \toprule
\arrayrulecolor{white}
Test1   & \gr Good & \re Bad  \\ \midrule
test2   & \ye OK   & \re Bad  \\ \midrule
test3   & \gr Good & \gr Good \\ 
\arrayrulecolor{black}           \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

I know it's not pretty, but it works - for row seperation =).