# color overhang with rowcolors in a table

Tags: color, colortbl, rowcolor

I load `xcolor` with option `table`, to get alternating row colors

However, I can't remove the color padding before the text of the first column (when using `@{}`.

In xcolor documentation, I see options for controlling it with the `\columncolor` command, but NOT with the `\rowcolors`. Here is the improper table (image below):

```latex
\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames,svgnames*,x11names*,table}{xcolor}
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{tabularx,longtable}  % longtable is used in other places of the full document.
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{colortbl}  % tabularx complains that \columncolor is undefined
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\rowcolors{1}{}{gray!25}%[0pt]
\footnotesize%
\begin{tabularx}{1.2\linewidth}{@{}p{21mm}*{2}{p{9mm}}p{12mm}p{14mm} *{3}{X} p{9mm} X@{}}
\toprule
{} & Ref & van Muut 2012 & (1)\newline original\newline siteMPL & (2)\newline original\newline branchMPL & (3)\newline cleaned\newline branchMPL & (4)\newline fsa\newline branchMPL & (5)\newline fsa+cleaned\newline branchMPL & (6)\newline fsa\newline Beast & (7)\newline fsa+cleaned\newline Beast \tabularnewline
\midrule
Cebidae         & 16,07 & 19,10 & 18,60 & 19,97 & 19,61 & 19,60 & 18,11 & 13,84 & 12,35 \tabularnewline
Platyrrhini     & 19,68 & 25,30 & 22,67 & 22,69 & 22,41 & 22,39 & 20,71 & 18,79 & 17,41 \tabularnewline
Pan             &  2,82 &  2,70 &  1,41 &  1,37 &  1,29 &  1,31 &  1,17 &  1,55 &  1,31 \tabularnewline
HomoPan         &  6,65 &  7,90 &  4,51 &  4,50 &  4,28 &  4,32 &  3,83 &  4,12 &  3,62 \tabularnewline
Homininae       &  9,06 & 10,50 &  6,24 &  6,15 &  5,96 &  5,96 &  5,52 &  6,02 &  5,36 \tabularnewline
Hominidae       & 15,76 & 20,30 & 13,06 & 13,00 & 12,69 & 12,66 & 11,79 & 11,74 & 10,37 \tabularnewline
Hominoidea      & 20,19 & 24,00 & 16,37 & 15,78 & 15,32 & 15,26 & 14,63 & 14,93 & 13,46 \tabularnewline
Catarrhini      & 29,44 & 32,60 & 27,60 & 27,27 & 26,69 & 26,71 & 24,71 & 24,47 & 22,67 \tabularnewline
Cercopithecidae & 19,42 & 21,90 & 14,71 & 14,39 & 13,56 & 13,54 & 12,21 & 11,79 & 10,66 \tabularnewline
Cercopithecinae & 13,75 & 16,20 & 10,40 & 10,15 &  9,33 &  9,34 &  8,15 &  7,94 &  7,10 \tabularnewline
Papionini       & 12,40 & 13,20 &  6,58 &  6,42 &  5,82 &  5,78 &  4,79 &  5,67 &  5,04 \tabularnewline
Macaca          &  5,28 &  8,50 &  2,16 &  2,23 &  2,04 &  2,07 &  1,84 &  2,49 &  2,17 \tabularnewline
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Median speciation ages by procedure, in My.}\label{tab:median-ages}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: Left corner of the table]

I tried :

1. `\rowcolors{1}{}{gray!25}[0pt]` but the command does not take options
2. defining my first column with `@{\columncolor{}[0pt][\tabcolsep]}p{21mm}`, but it keeps complaining:

   ```
    ! Undefined control sequence.
    <template> ...rstrutbox \d@llarbegin \columncolor 
                                                  {}[0pt][\tabcolsep]\relax \d@llar...
    l.30 \end{tabularx}
   ```
3. `@{\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}}p{21mm}`: no effect.
4. Inserting `\fct` before the row throws an "undefined control sequence" as well, although based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/507074/95423), this is exactly what I need.

   ```
    ! Undefined control sequence.
    <recently read> \fct 

    l.30 \end{tabularx}
   ```

These answers didn't help:

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/365988/95423

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31704/95423

Comment: Entirely unrelated to the issue itself but are you aware that your table is a lot wider than the textwidth? Also some of the column headers are in fact wider than the corresponding columns causeing cut/ overlapping text and quite a lot of overfull box warnings.

Comment: Regarding: "Inserting \fct before the row throws an "undefined control sequence"", it might be useful to show which error message you got specifically. Which control sequence is undefined?

Comment: @leandriis oh sorry about the width, it's expected in the original document (where \textwidth is 18.5 cm). + I added the \fct error.

Comment: If you remove `@{}` at begin column specification, it will work as you expect. However, if you like to have it, than see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/365685/row-colour-gaps-in-tabularx-with-aboverulesep-and/365698#365698

Comment: the width is too large, but I use \centerfloat to expand into both margins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two versions of your table.

Since you mention getting `! Undefined control sequence. <recently read> \fct` when trying to use `\fct` inside of your table, please be aware, that you also have to add the definition of `\cft` into your document. In the following example, I have done so and also adapted the definition according to your color definition.

Since the table is wider than the textwidth, I have also added a second example in which I have shortened the column headers. Their meaning is exaplained below the table. Additionally, I have eused `siunitx` in order to align the numbers with respect to the decimal separator. (In the comments you mentioned having a wider textblock than in this example, but using `\begin{tabularx}{1.2\textwidth}`will always result in a table that is wider than the textwidth, regardless of the actual value of textwidth.)

[image]

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames,svgnames*,x11names*,table}{xcolor}
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{tabularx,longtable}  % longtable is used in other places of the full document.
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xcolor}

%%% added for the second example
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{makecell}


\newcommand*{\fct}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{>{\columncolor{gray!25}\hspace*{-\tabcolsep}}l}{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\rowcolors{1}{}{gray!25}%[0pt]
\footnotesize%
\begin{tabularx}{1.2\linewidth}{@{}l*{2}{p{9mm}}p{12mm}p{14mm} *{3}{X} p{9mm} X@{}}
\toprule
{} & Ref & van Muut 2012 & (1)\newline original\newline siteMPL & (2)\newline original\newline branchMPL & (3)\newline cleaned\newline branchMPL & (4)\newline fsa\newline branchMPL & (5)\newline fsa+cleaned\newline branchMPL & (6)\newline fsa\newline Beast & (7)\newline fsa+cleaned\newline Beast \tabularnewline
\midrule
\fct{Cebidae}         & 16,07 & 19,10 & 18,60 & 19,97 & 19,61 & 19,60 & 18,11 & 13,84 & 12,35 \tabularnewline
Platyrrhini     & 19,68 & 25,30 & 22,67 & 22,69 & 22,41 & 22,39 & 20,71 & 18,79 & 17,41 \tabularnewline
\fct{Pan }            &  2,82 &  2,70 &  1,41 &  1,37 &  1,29 &  1,31 &  1,17 &  1,55 &  1,31 \tabularnewline
HomoPan         &  6,65 &  7,90 &  4,51 &  4,50 &  4,28 &  4,32 &  3,83 &  4,12 &  3,62 \tabularnewline
\fct{Homininae}       &  9,06 & 10,50 &  6,24 &  6,15 &  5,96 &  5,96 &  5,52 &  6,02 &  5,36 \tabularnewline
Hominidae       & 15,76 & 20,30 & 13,06 & 13,00 & 12,69 & 12,66 & 11,79 & 11,74 & 10,37 \tabularnewline
\fct{Hominoidea}      & 20,19 & 24,00 & 16,37 & 15,78 & 15,32 & 15,26 & 14,63 & 14,93 & 13,46 \tabularnewline
Catarrhini      & 29,44 & 32,60 & 27,60 & 27,27 & 26,69 & 26,71 & 24,71 & 24,47 & 22,67 \tabularnewline
\fct{Cercopithecidae} & 19,42 & 21,90 & 14,71 & 14,39 & 13,56 & 13,54 & 12,21 & 11,79 & 10,66 \tabularnewline
Cercopithecinae & 13,75 & 16,20 & 10,40 & 10,15 &  9,33 &  9,34 &  8,15 &  7,94 &  7,10 \tabularnewline
\fct{Papionini}       & 12,40 & 13,20 &  6,58 &  6,42 &  5,82 &  5,78 &  4,79 &  5,67 &  5,04 \tabularnewline
Macaca          &  5,28 &  8,50 &  2,16 &  2,23 &  2,04 &  2,07 &  1,84 &  2,49 &  2,17 \tabularnewline
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Median speciation ages by procedure, in My.}\label{tab:median-ages}
\end{table}


\begin{table}[h]
\footnotesize%
\sisetup{input-ignore={.},
         input-decimal-markers={,}, 
         output-decimal-marker = {,}}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}l*{9}{S}}
\toprule
{} 
  & {\thead{Ref}}  & {\thead{van Muut\\ 2012}} & {(1)}& {(2)} & {(3)}  & {(4)} & {(5)}  & {(6)} & {(7)} \\
\midrule
Cebidae         & 16,07 & 19,10 & 18,60 & 19,97 & 19,61 & 19,60 & 18,11 & 13,84 & 12,35 \\
Platyrrhini     & 19,68 & 25,30 & 22,67 & 22,69 & 22,41 & 22,39 & 20,71 & 18,79 & 17,41 \\
Pan             &  2,82 &  2,70 &  1,41 &  1,37 &  1,29 &  1,31 &  1,17 &  1,55 &  1,31 \\
HomoPan         &  6,65 &  7,90 &  4,51 &  4,50 &  4,28 &  4,32 &  3,83 &  4,12 &  3,62 \\
Homininae       &  9,06 & 10,50 &  6,24 &  6,15 &  5,96 &  5,96 &  5,52 &  6,02 &  5,36 \\
Hominidae       & 15,76 & 20,30 & 13,06 & 13,00 & 12,69 & 12,66 & 11,79 & 11,74 & 10,37 \\
Hominoidea      & 20,19 & 24,00 & 16,37 & 15,78 & 15,32 & 15,26 & 14,63 & 14,93 & 13,46 \\
Catarrhini      & 29,44 & 32,60 & 27,60 & 27,27 & 26,69 & 26,71 & 24,71 & 24,47 & 22,67 \\
Cercopithecidae & 19,42 & 21,90 & 14,71 & 14,39 & 13,56 & 13,54 & 12,21 & 11,79 & 10,66 \\
Cercopithecinae & 13,75 & 16,20 & 10,40 & 10,15 &  9,33 &  9,34 &  8,15 &  7,94 &  7,10 \\
Papionini       & 12,40 & 13,20 &  6,58 &  6,42 &  5,82 &  5,78 &  4,79 &  5,67 &  5,04 \\
Macaca          &  5,28 &  8,50 &  2,16 &  2,23 &  2,04 &  2,07 &  1,84 &  2,49 &  2,17 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
(1) = original siteMPL, (2) = original branchMPL, (3) = cleaned branchMPL, (4) =  fsa branchMPL, (5) =  fsa+cleaned branchMPL, (6) =  fsa Beast, (7) =  fsa+cleaned Beast
\caption{Median speciation ages by procedure, in My.}\label{tab:median-ages}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice!!! My bad, I totally overlooked the definitions of these commands in the original answer.

Comment: In definition of `\fct`, `\columncolor{gray!25}` is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I rename `\fct` to more meaningful name, and also fix the color overhang at the last column.

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames,svgnames*,x11names*,table}{xcolor}
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{tabularx,longtable}  % longtable is used in other places of the full document.
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xcolor}


\newcommand*{\killLeftColsep}[2]{%
  \multicolumn{1}{>{\hspace*{-\tabcolsep}}#1}{#2}}
\newcommand*{\killRightColsep}[2]{%
  \multicolumn{1}{#1<{\hspace*{-\tabcolsep}}}{#2}}
  
\newcommand*{\klcl}{\killLeftColsep{l}}
\newcommand*{\krcl}{\killRightColsep{l}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
  \rowcolors{1}{}{gray!25}
  \footnotesize%
  \begin{tabularx}{1.2\linewidth}{@{}l *{2}{p{9mm}} p{12mm} p{14mm} *{3}{X} p{9mm} X@{}}
    \toprule
    {} & Ref 
       & van Muut 2012 
       & (1)\newline original\newline siteMPL 
       & (2)\newline original\newline branchMPL 
       & (3)\newline cleaned\newline branchMPL 
       & (4)\newline fsa\newline branchMPL 
       & (5)\newline fsa+cleaned\newline branchMPL 
       & (6)\newline fsa\newline Beast 
       & (7)\newline fsa+cleaned\newline Beast \\ \midrule
    \klcl{Cebidae}         & 16,07 & 19,10 & 18,60 & 19,97 & 19,61 & 19,60 & 18,11 & 13,84 & \krcl{12,35} \\
    Platyrrhini            & 19,68 & 25,30 & 22,67 & 22,69 & 22,41 & 22,39 & 20,71 & 18,79 & \krcl{17,41} \\
    \klcl{Pan}             & 2,82  & 2,70  & 1,41  & 1,37  & 1,29  & 1,31  & 1,17  & 1,55  & \krcl{1,31}  \\
    HomoPan                & 6,65  & 7,90  & 4,51  & 4,50  & 4,28  & 4,32  & 3,83  & 4,12  & \krcl{3,62}  \\
    \klcl{Homininae}       & 9,06  & 10,50 & 6,24  & 6,15  & 5,96  & 5,96  & 5,52  & 6,02  & \krcl{5,36}  \\
    Hominidae              & 15,76 & 20,30 & 13,06 & 13,00 & 12,69 & 12,66 & 11,79 & 11,74 & \krcl{10,37} \\
    \klcl{Hominoidea}      & 20,19 & 24,00 & 16,37 & 15,78 & 15,32 & 15,26 & 14,63 & 14,93 & \krcl{13,46} \\
    Catarrhini             & 29,44 & 32,60 & 27,60 & 27,27 & 26,69 & 26,71 & 24,71 & 24,47 & \krcl{22,67} \\
    \klcl{Cercopithecidae} & 19,42 & 21,90 & 14,71 & 14,39 & 13,56 & 13,54 & 12,21 & 11,79 & \krcl{10,66} \\
    Cercopithecinae        & 13,75 & 16,20 & 10,40 & 10,15 & 9,33  & 9,34  & 8,15  & 7,94  & \krcl{7,10}  \\
    \klcl{Papionini}       & 12,40 & 13,20 & 6,58  & 6,42  & 5,82  & 5,78  & 4,79  & 5,67  & \krcl{5,04}  \\
    Macaca                 & 5,28  & 8,50  & 2,16  & 2,23  & 2,04  & 2,07  & 1,84  & 2,49  & \krcl{2,17}  \\ \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
  \caption{Median speciation ages by procedure, in My.}\label{tab:median-ages}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With `{NiceTabularX}` of `nicematrix` (≥ 6.21 of 2023-07-14), you have no problem with color padding.

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames,svgnames*,x11names*,table}{xcolor}
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]

\footnotesize%
\begin{NiceTabularX}{1.2\linewidth}{@{}p{21mm}*{2}{p{9mm}}p{12mm}p{14mm} *{3}{X} p{9mm} X@{}}[color-inside]
\toprule
{} & Ref & van Muut 2012 & (1)\newline original\newline siteMPL & (2)\newline original\newline branchMPL & (3)\newline cleaned\newline branchMPL & (4)\newline fsa\newline branchMPL & (5)\newline fsa+cleaned\newline branchMPL & (6)\newline fsa\newline Beast & (7)\newline fsa+cleaned\newline Beast \tabularnewline
\midrule
\rowcolors{gray!25}{}
Cebidae         & 16,07 & 19,10 & 18,60 & 19,97 & 19,61 & 19,60 & 18,11 & 13,84 & 12,35 \tabularnewline
Platyrrhini     & 19,68 & 25,30 & 22,67 & 22,69 & 22,41 & 22,39 & 20,71 & 18,79 & 17,41 \tabularnewline
Pan             &  2,82 &  2,70 &  1,41 &  1,37 &  1,29 &  1,31 &  1,17 &  1,55 &  1,31 \tabularnewline
HomoPan         &  6,65 &  7,90 &  4,51 &  4,50 &  4,28 &  4,32 &  3,83 &  4,12 &  3,62 \tabularnewline
Homininae       &  9,06 & 10,50 &  6,24 &  6,15 &  5,96 &  5,96 &  5,52 &  6,02 &  5,36 \tabularnewline
Hominidae       & 15,76 & 20,30 & 13,06 & 13,00 & 12,69 & 12,66 & 11,79 & 11,74 & 10,37 \tabularnewline
Hominoidea      & 20,19 & 24,00 & 16,37 & 15,78 & 15,32 & 15,26 & 14,63 & 14,93 & 13,46 \tabularnewline
Catarrhini      & 29,44 & 32,60 & 27,60 & 27,27 & 26,69 & 26,71 & 24,71 & 24,47 & 22,67 \tabularnewline
Cercopithecidae & 19,42 & 21,90 & 14,71 & 14,39 & 13,56 & 13,54 & 12,21 & 11,79 & 10,66 \tabularnewline
Cercopithecinae & 13,75 & 16,20 & 10,40 & 10,15 &  9,33 &  9,34 &  8,15 &  7,94 &  7,10 \tabularnewline
Papionini       & 12,40 & 13,20 &  6,58 &  6,42 &  5,82 &  5,78 &  4,79 &  5,67 &  5,04 \tabularnewline
Macaca          &  5,28 &  8,50 &  2,16 &  2,23 &  2,04 &  2,07 &  1,84 &  2,49 &  2,17 \tabularnewline
\bottomrule
\end{NiceTabularX}
\caption{Median speciation ages by procedure, in My.}\label{tab:median-ages}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]